# Why the PHP output is not displaying on webpage?

Tags: php, prepared-statement, ob-start

I am not getting any output from this php code shows blank page

```
 <?php
include 'conn.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php include('callheadcss.php');?>
</head>
<body>
```

**Div to show php Output**

```
<div id="slidey">
<ul>
<?php
```

working with prepare statement

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM sliderimg');

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0)
{
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$imgpath=$row['SliderImg'];
echo '<li><img src="'.$imgpath.'"><p class="title">'. $row['Event_name'] .'</p><p class="description">'. $row['Eventdate'] .'</p></li>';    
}
}
?>
</ul>       
    </div>
</body>
```

**script for slider**

```
<script src="designcss/js/jquery.slidey.js"></script>
    <script src="designcss/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#slidey").slidey({
                interval: 8000,
                listCount: 5,
                autoplay: false,
                showList: true
            });
            $(".slidey-list-description").dotdotdot();
        </script>
```

Comment: Any error messages? Is PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: you don't have to use $stmt->store_result() to have access to $stmt->num_rows ? http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: @MacBooc ..can you please add this?

Comment: @BenRoob no sir .there is no error at all. just a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result->store_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
```

by php.net :

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.
>
> If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.

[php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Comment: @krish edit : $stmt -> $result and var_dump($result->num_rows) to be sure that it bigger than 0

Comment: sir i already checked this and all is ok..but still the problem exists.

Comment: if you are really sure that $numRows is bigger than 1 then i can't help you

Answer (score -1):

Quick suggestions:

- add some dummy text like lorem ipsum right after the `<body>` tag: if it does not show then your problem is not related to your PHP script
- use `var_dump($numRows)` to be sure that there is a least a row to be used

Comment: insert this one but noting happen

Comment: @krish have you checked the source code of the page? It's possible to have both some HTML and a blank page at the same time

Comment: sir i have checked everything.it showing me html <div> then <ul> but after that nothing appers on the page.. it showing this  on source page >>>>><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php include('callheadcss.php');?>
</head>
<body>
Div to show php Output

<div id="slidey">
<ul>

Comment: after <ul> blank apears on the page

Comment: yes sir i have also checked it there is no error.from my cpanel> Metrics > Errors.

Answer (score -1):

try to print $row using

`print_r($row);`

This will print $row in array format so you can see all data are coming or not

Comment: check your console is it showing any js error and blank page can show array output if it is null then also it will give you some output

Comment: Expected end of value but found ‘\9 ’.  Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  in console